# How to set watermark image in php

Tags: php, laravel

I set same size watermark in two different upload image , watermark size is same but uploaded image height,width,Size and Dimension are different .so set watermark in image is different height, width.. So how can i set same size of watermark of any image?

please check Below uploded image link.In this image 'ONLYGEMS' is watermark.

1) http://groomies.cosmonautgroup.com/public/assets/image/2016-ford-focus-rs-front-4k-uhd-wallpaper-806x41915640362249.jpg

2) http://groomies.cosmonautgroup.com/public/assets/image/img_005215640307093.jpg

3) http://groomies.cosmonautgroup.com/public/assets/image/pgfaviconblck515640317244.png

```
$watermark      = imagecreatefrompng($watermark);

switch(mime_content_type($imageUrl)) {

case 'image/png':
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($imageUrl);
        break;
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $image          = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageUrl);
        break;
    case 'image/jpg':
        $image          = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageUrl);
        break;
    default:
        $image = null; 
}

$watermarkX     = imagesx($watermark);

$watermarkY     = imagesy($watermark);

$width          = imagesx($image);

$height         = imagesy($image);

$xPosition      = $width / 8;

$yPosition      = $height - ($height /3);

$img_w = imagesx($image);

$img_h = imagesy($image);

$wtrmrk_w = imagesx($watermark);

$wtrmrk_h = imagesy($watermark);

$dst_x = ($img_w / 2) - ($wtrmrk_w / 2); // For centering the watermark on any image

$dst_y = ($img_h / 2) - ($wtrmrk_h / 2); // For centering the watermark on any image

imagecopy($image, $watermark, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $wtrmrk_w, $wtrmrk_h);

switch(mime_content_type($imageUrl)) {
  case 'image/png':
    imagepng($image,$imageUrl);
    break;
  case 'image/jpeg':
    imagejpeg($image,$imageUrl,100);
    break;
  default:
    $image = null; 
}
```

Comment: pls, provide some description don't put only code.

Comment: @Nikunj Chaklasiya , I provide Some description so give me solution

Comment: Please provide some image examples. You can post to some free hosting service and put the URLs here.

Comment: @MitulPatel here your solution https://www.codermen.com/blog/104/add-watermark-on-an-images-in-laravel-5-8-step-by-step refer this link

Comment: @fmw42 please check Below imgae link
In this image 'ONLYGEMS' is watermark.
1)
http://groomies.cosmonautgroup.com/public/assets/image/2016-ford-focus-rs-front-4k-uhd-wallpaper-806x41915640362249.jpg
2) 
http://groomies.cosmonautgroup.com/public/assets/image/img_005215640307093.jpg
3) http://groomies.cosmonautgroup.com/public/assets/image/pgfaviconblck515640317244.png

Comment: The watermarks are the same size. It is the background image that changes and when displayed it gets reduced in size so it can all be seen and thus the watermark text "looks" smaller. If you need it to look similar, then you need to resize the watermark image in proportion to the dimensions of the background image.

Comment: @fmw42 ..thanks i will try it

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library: http://image.intervention.io/
Intervention Image is an open source PHP image handling and manipulation library. It provides an easier and expressive way to create, edit, and compose images and supports currently the two most common image processing libraries GD Library and Imagick.